# How to alias date object property?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have encountered troubles when trying to declare readonly property alias
to an internal `var` (which actually is a `Date` object). Here is an example
which reproduces it on my laptop:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 62
    color: time.getTime() === internal.time.getTime() ? "green" : "red"

    readonly property alias time: internal.time

    onTimeChanged: {
        if (typeof time === "undefined") return
        console.log("time:", Qt.formatDateTime(time), time.getTime())
        console.assert(time.getTime() === internal.time.getTime(), "not
equal")
    }

    Component.onCompleted: internal.time = new Date(1403621359000)

    QtObject {
        id: internal
        property var time: undefined
    }
}
```

The value reported by outer time property is indeed a strictly one hour
earlier what leads me to a conclusion that, probably, day saving time
mechanism may be involved.

If I replace `alias` with `var`, the value is as expected, though.

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of? What could cause such
behaviour? The expectation is that alias should not do any
transformations/conversions on aliased value.